# From SOAP to XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

So I'm trying to convert (Extract) all the elements within the body of a SOAP document into XML using XSLT. Here's my SOAP document (complete)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dealercode.xsl"?>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <AuthHeader xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/">
            <LogonID></LogonID>
            <Password></Password>
        </AuthHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <getDealerCodeById xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/">
            <BrokerCode>{ssQuoterBrokerCode(app_id)}</BrokerCode>
            <IDNumber>{dealerCode}</IDNumber>
        </getDealerCodeById>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And Here's my XSLT sheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dealercode2soap.xsl"?>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
<xsl:value-of select="soap:Body/s:getDealerCodeById"
     xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" 
     xmlns:s="http://somedomainname/" />
```

```
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output is not what I want. It is still parsing the whole SOAP document instead of just giving me the contents within the "soap:Body" elements and it I am also getting a warning of "unresolved namespace prefix soap"

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: I managed to get it to work making use of a different block of code. See below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns ="http://www.somedomainename.com">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It now outputs in my browser the contents of the body section. The other most important thing I realized was that formatting was done on the server side but since I did not have access to the server at the time I had no idea whether my code was working or not. This is the desired output I was looking for (which was apparently working the whole time.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<getDealerCodeById xmlns="http:///" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <BrokerCode>{ssQuoterBrokerCode(app_id)}</BrokerCode>
   <IDNumber>{dealerCode}</IDNumber>
</getDealerCodeById>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the warning about "*Unresolved namespace prefix soap*" because you have not declared the `soap` namespace in your XSLT.

Also, your `getDealerCodeById` element is bound to the `http://somedomainname/` namespace-uri. You may not have noticed, because it does not use a namespace-prefix:  `xmlns="http://somedomainname/"`

Be sure to declare both the `soap` namespace and the `http://somedomainname/` namespace in your XSLT and adjust your XPath to use whatever namespace-prefix you declare:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="soap:Body/s:getDealerCodeById"
         xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" 
         xmlns:s="http://somedomainname/" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Mads but it does not seem to be working. I declared the namespace as advised (basically copied your code from above) - any other thoughts??

Comment: That should work. Tested with you sample doc(after creating a document element to make it valid XML). You could have a type-o or maybe other namespaces mixed in. Can you post a more complete example of your input XML and your XSLT?

Comment: Just re-read and saw your note about the soap namespace not being declared as well. I have updated my answer. You need to have all namespaces declared in your XSLT in order to be able to use them in your XPath.

Comment: Updated my code as requested (see intitial post) and when I run the code and view the page source - it is still parsing the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the code in your question means that we can't see what question Mads was answering, which make it very difficult to follow the thread. But the situation with your code as it is right now is that you bind the soap prefix to different namespaces in the source document and the stylesheet, which is not illegal but is certainly confusing and unlikely to be what you intended. The namespace for somedomain.com doesn't match either.

I would expect the effect of these errors to be that your stylesheet outputs nothing. I don't know what you mean by saying "it is parsing the whole document" - stylesheets always parse the whole input document. Do you mean it is outputting the whole of the input document? That certainly doesn't seem consistent with your code.

Comment: You're quite right Michael. It is outputting nothing and it is outputting "the whole of the input document". Any wisdom?

Comment: What do you mean? How on earth can it output nothing and output the whole of the input document at the same time?

Comment: My apologies Michael. What I meant to say is that I get no output in my browser.

Comment: Hey folk, please see edit above. It is producing the desired output. My apologies for some of the confusion being new to XSLT and programming in general. Please add any thoughts on where I could possible refine the edited code and thanks for all the help